# How would I approached selecting the same column in a SQL DB multiple times displaying different data?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

When I query the Database I use the following statement:

```
SELECT 
    count(code) as total_codes,
    count(code) as reserved
FROM 
    "tablename"
WHERE 
    redeemed = 'TRUE'
```

This command successfully returns an output however both columns are the same.

I would like to see one column displaying the total amount of codes and an additional column that displays how many of those codes have been redeemed.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using the same calculation for both the columns.

To get the total codes, use `count(distinct code)`. To get the count of redeemed codes use a `case` expression. Only rows with redeemed = 'TRUE' will be counted.

```
SELECT count(distinct code) as total_codes,
       count(distinct case when redeemed='TRUE' then code end) as reserved
FROM "tablename"
```

Comment: I want add some aditional comment. You only need `distinct code` if your `code` column isnt PK. The second count work because if you dont put an `ELSE` part for the `CASE`  will return null. And `COUNT` only count not null values.

Comment: If it's possible to have duplicate codes then you'll also need `DISTINCT` in the second `COUNT` as well.

Comment: @TomH..agreed.included `distinct`.